# Underlining User Input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, underline

I am intending to underline the user input but after doing research, I still cant find the way to do it.

So far this is what I have got from doing research, but it still doesn't work.
Anyone knows how to solve it? or rather the proper method to do it?

What if I am using **read -p "What is your name: " name** instead of the one below? As what I am expecting for the output is.

**What is your name? (the input from user and is underlined)**

```
function underlineInput()
{
PS1='\033[4;47;40m'
}

function UNunderlineInput()
{
PS1='\033[0;47;40m'
}

function hi()
{
echo "Please enter your name: "
underlineInput
read input
underlineInput
}
```

Thanks to those who helped in advance!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the escape sequence to turn on underlining at the end of the prompt, then send the back-to-normal-sequence afterward:

```
read -p $'Please enter your name: \033[4m' name
printf '\033[0m' # Use printf instead of echo to avoid newline, and it translates escape without $''
```

BTW, if you want this script to work on other types of terminal as well, you can use the terminfo database to get the relevant escape (/whatever) sequences.  The terminfo capability names for underlining on and off are "smul" and "rmul":

```
read -p "Please enter your name: $(tput smul)" name
tput rmul
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link [here](http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2008/01/ansi-escape-sequences-for-writing-text.html)

But its just:

```
$ echo -e "\033[4mThis is a underlined line.\033[0m"
```

The key parts are the `\033[4m` to underline and `\033[0m` to change it back.

Comment: hi Grammin, what if I am using 
read -p "What is your name?: " name

Comment: @Andres I would do something like: echo -n "What is your name"; read var; echo "\033[4mHi $var\033[0m"